# Android bluetooth connection fails (Error: no bt sock found, scn 1)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wrote a little application for Android 2.3 using Eclipse Galileo. 
The application is based on Bluetooth Chat example published on Google.

The problem is that bluetooth connection fails. 
I connect my Android with Bluetooth access point via SPP - serial port profile). 
The reasons why the connection fails are not clear for me. 
I see the following in logs:

```
10-09 18:52:35.989: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(162): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/18286/hci0/dev_00_1A_7D_0A_B7_5F
10-09 18:58:35.239: ERROR/(18269): ****************search UUID = 1101***********
10-09 18:58:35.489: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(162): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/18286/hci0/dev_00_1A_7D_0A_B7_5F
10-09 18:58:35.529: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(162): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/18286/hci0/dev_00_1A_7D_0A_B7_5F

10-09 18:58:35.669: ERROR/BLZ20_WRAPPER(20769): ##### ERROR : btlif_process_con_rsp: no bt sock found, scn 1#####
```

Any help is appreciable

Comment: Are You using Samsung device? I've just faced the same issue on galaxy ace.

Comment: Does it connect and then disconnect or not connect at all? Post your code to set up a connection.

Comment: 1. The log above is written from Samsung S5510 (galaxy mini). 2. The problem is already gone and as I understood it was related to UUID. I've changed UUID to this one presented somewhere in web: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB.  After that the message with BLZ20_WRAPPER didnt' appear anymore.

Comment: Strangely, I already use this UUID and I still get this error.

Comment: Jepp me too - using different Samsung Devices, so far this error is occasionally appearing on a Samsung Galaxy SII (GT-I9100), I am using the same UUID as stated above.

Comment: In addition: This mostly happens when I switch between bluetooth devices (SPP Printers) like: Switch on Printer A, print, switch Printer A off, Switch on Printer B, print, switch it off, switch on Printer A, print ..... Plus: I always close the socket connection right after printing, as otherwise I had a lot of trouble, with the Bixolon SPP getting into a messed up and unrecoverable state

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to a bug in the samsung bluetooth stack related to SSP connections.

check this link out:
 http://www.samsunggalaxysforum.com/firmware-problems/connection-problems-sgs-bluetooth-spp-device/

One solution I had was if I detected a blutooth error in my app on a samsung device in software I would turn off the bluetooth wait 5 seconds and turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you using wrong UUID
 UUID should be 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

If UUID is wrong not able to connect.